# How to reduce the number of file writes when there are multiple threads?

Tags: java, performance, serialization, file-io, concurrency

here's the situation.

In a Java Web App i was assigned to mantain, i've been asked to improve the general response time for the stress tests during QA. This web app doesn't use a database, since it was supposed to be light and simple. (And i can't change that decision)

To persist configuration, i've found that everytime you make a change to it, a general object containing lists of config objects is serialized to a file.

Using Jmeter i've found that in the given test case, there are 2 requests taking up the most of the time. Both these requests add or change some configuration objects. Since the access to the file must be sinchronized, when many users are changing config, the file must be fully written several times in a few seconds, and requests are waiting for the file writing to happen.

I have thought that all these serializations are not necessary at all, since we are rewriting the most of the objects again and again, the changes in every request are to one single object, but the file is written as a whole every time.

So, is there a way to reduce the number of real file writes but still guarantee that all changes are eventually serialized?

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Why do you store the configuration as serialized objects?

Comment: It was not my choice, the designer thought it would be nice and simple, unfortunately, he's not around to see the results and i'm in charge of "making it fast enough for QA guys"... Any way i can't change that in the near future, since design has been approved and functional testing is over. Changing its roots to use [db4o](http://db4o.com/) or JavaDB would take us back to development stage acording to politics... and at least a 3 week delay. I hate now being responsible for such a poor design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to do changes in memory and keep one thread on the background, running at given intervals and flushing the changes to the disk. Keep in mind, that in the case of crash you'll lost data that wasn't flushed.

The background thread could be scheduled with a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

IMO, it would be better idea to use a DB. Can't you use an embedded DB like [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)? These databases support concurrent access and can also guarantee the consistency of data in case of crash.

Comment: Thanks! changing the writings to every few seconds instead of multiple writes a second has done wonders for the response time on these requests, as expected, they no longer wait for serialization to complete.

Comment: Good to know. I hope you can change this design ASAP, it is really awful to work with systems like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely cannot use a database, the obvious solution is to break your single file into multiple files, one file for each of config objects. It would speedup serialization and output process as well as reduce lock contention (requests that change different config objects may write their files simultaneously, though it may become IO-bound).

Comment: I tried dividing the writes in various files, and it has reduced the response time, unfortunately as you point out, during the peak loads it also becomes io-bound and responses delay a lot. (but not as much as when it was a single file).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to to do what Lucene does and not actually overwrite the old file at all, but to write a new file that only contains the "updates". This relies on your updates being associative but that is usually the case anyway.

The idea is that if your old file contains "8" and you have 3 updates you write "3" to the new file, and the new state is "11", next you write "-2" and you now have "9". Periodically you can aggregate the old and the updates. Any physical file you write is never updated, but may be deleted once it is no longer used.

To make this idea a bit more relevant consider if the numbers above are records of some kind. "3" could translate to "Add three new records" and "-2" to "Delete these two records".

Lucene is an example of a project that uses this style of additive update strategy very successfully.